# emplace_back is faster than allocate once + move in c++11?

Tags: c++, performance, c++11

I have two fuctions:

f2 - first allocate memory , then move data.

f - deallocate + move = emplace_back.

I am trying to understand what is faster and better to use in terms of performance and code quality?

```
void f2(const std::vector<std::string>& users) {
    std::vector<std::pair<std::string, int>> userOccurancies(users.size());

    auto userOcIt = userOccurancies.begin();
    for (const auto & user : users) {
        userOcIt->first = std::move(user);
        userOcIt->second = 0;
        userOcIt++;
    }
}

void f(const std::vector<std::string>& users) {
    std::vector < std::pair<std::string, std::size_t>> userCount;
    userCount.reserve(users.size());

    for (auto& user : users) {
        userCount.emplace_back(user, 0);
    }
}
```

As for performance I tried to check it with MS VS2019 profiler but it always gives me different results if a swap calls of these funcions with each other: `f2(users);f(users);` and `f(users);f2(users);` gives different call tree.

Can you help me?

What is faster and better to use in terms of performance and code quality?

I use only c++11.

Comment: Do note that `userOcIt->first = std::move(user);` is going to make a copy, not a move since `user` is `const` and you can't move something that is constant.

Comment: Also, if you want to micro-benchmark, check out http://quick-bench.com/

Comment: the difference by swapping the order of the calls is most likely due to caching. To properly profile you need to take a lot of samples do the average (and possibly discard aberant results)

Comment: They would take roughly the same time. The second one is shorter and more clear.

Comment: The first may be slower because the vector is initialized with many default constructed values. Indeed, this will cause more data to be read/written from/to the memory hierarchy and should be thus slower if the array is big enough (eg. your vector does not fit in the CPU caches).

Comment: Hopefully you are testing a release version that has optimizations turned on.  If you're testing a "debug" version, then note that Visual C++ debug runtime is non-optimized and adds a **lot** of iterator validation checks.

Comment: [Demo](http://quick-bench.com/dJw_6qW8j9kc5quJjrsQ-5xlmGw) but care, as size of vector/string might be relevant.

Answer (score 0):

I tested it with quick-bench website and the code from the post has results that f2() (allocate + copy) will be slower than f() (emplace_back) on both gcc and clang c++11 -O3.

But after that I slightly changed code:

```
void f2(benchmark::State& state) {
    std::vector<std::string> users = { "john", "atest", "qwe" };
  for (auto _ : state) {
    std::vector<std::pair<std::string, int>> userOccurancies(users.size());

    auto userOcIt = userOccurancies.begin();
    for (auto && user : users) {
        userOcIt->first = std::move(user);
        userOcIt->second = 0;
        userOcIt++;
    }
  }
}
// Register the function as a benchmark
BENCHMARK(f2);

void f(benchmark::State& state) {
      std::vector<std::string> users = { "john", "atest", "qwe" };
  for (auto _ : state) {
    std::vector < std::pair<std::string, std::size_t>> userCount;
    userCount.reserve(users.size());

    for (auto&& user : users) {
        userCount.emplace_back(user, 0);
    }
  }
}
BENCHMARK(f);
```

Don't know how long this link will work http://quick-bench.com/CZIVnB4xVRBPpvw06GQ38FNkwws .

The main change - in `for` loop this time I remove `const` and take rvalue to value.

And now `f2(user);` works faster under c++11 -O3 gcc and clang so `emplace_back` loses this time.

f2() is 1.5 times **faster** than f().

But if `users` input argument will contain large data (8k elements) then f2() is 1.2 times **slower** than f().

***udpated due to @JérômeRichard comment***

Comment: Since the link might disappear, just include the basic result in the answer: `f2()` is 1.1 times faster than `f()`.

Comment: I am not sure your benchmark is correct since the slow initialization of `users` is in the benchmark loop! If this initialization is excluded of the benchmark, you get [significantly different results](http://quick-bench.com/EfmBikt4pmtR_1tpwBUzcyf2Ihw). Please note that we can actually [conclude the opposite](http://quick-bench.com/aB9Gm6EHWENVLOVfQvMYbFNgShI) with a large amount of users.

Comment: @JérômeRichard, yeah, great, thanks for more results!

Comment: @Jarod42, if i remove ```std::move(user);``` f2 will lose. Write what you suggest in terms of c++11 if it could be better by performance and/or code quality

Comment: I meant, move vector `users` inside the loop would be fair comparison (even if we add noise in comparison as then, vector construction would be part of timing)